# Foliation of surface all of whose leaves are circles

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, foliations

I'm having trouble locating a reference for the following basic fact.  Let $S$ be a compact orientable surface with boundary.  Assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is a foliation of $S$ all of whose leaves are closed circles.  Here I am assuming that the boundary components are themselves leaves of $\mathcal{F}$.  Then one of the following two things hold.

1. There is a homeomorphism $\psi : S \rightarrow [0,1] \times S^1$ that takes $\mathcal{F}$ to the foliation on $[0,1] \times S^1$ whose leaves are $x \times S^1$ for $x \in [0,1]$.
2. There is a homeomorphism $\psi : S \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ that takes $\mathcal{F}$ to the foliation on $S^1 \times S^1$ whose leaves are $x \times S^1$ for $x \in S^1$.

Can anyone provide such a reference?

Edit : I should remark that if $S$ is a *closed* surface, then Euler characteristic arguments show that $S$ has to be a torus (though I don't know why the foliation has to be of the above form).  However, if $S$ has nonempty boundary then I don't think that a simple Euler characteristic argument works.  The trouble is that this argument goes by constructing a non vanishing vector field, and any surface with nonempty boundary has a non vanishing vector field.

Comment: This follows because the surface $S$ (assumed connected) must be a circle bundle over a compact connected $1$-manifold with boundary (which might be empty), and there are only two of those.

Comment: @RobertBryant : Thanks!  I am a little embarrassed that I didn't see that...

Comment: One can also reduce the case of nonempty boundary to the closed case by doubling: Take two copies of the surface with boundary and identify their boundaries to get a closed surface. If you know the closed surface is a torus, the original surface must then be an annulus. (Doubling doubles the Euler characteristic.)

Comment: You find a classification of foliations of surfaces in the book by Gilbert Hector and Ulrich Hirsch.